# Cache for fast repeated file searches

Tags: python, caching, scandir

I have a disk array with several TB of poorly organized files.

A python program needs to access the files by name and doing a full search each time is very time-consuming.

What I did is to build a cache on file and searching the cache instead.

current code looks like:

```
pickle_file = 'fscopy.pickle'
if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
    # fscopy = pickle.load(pickle_file)
    with open(pickle_file, 'r') as infil:
        fscopy = json.load(infil)
else:
    # extl = {'mp3', 'PDF', 'prc', 'docx', 'txt', 'jpg', 'cue', 'pdf', 'zip', 'iso', 'nfo', 'odt', '7z', 'azw3', 'djvu',
    #         'lit', 'Pdf', 'rtf', 'bin', 'wv', 'doc', 'chm', 'RAR', 'epub', 'pdF', 'gz', 'cbz', 'cbr', 'rar', 'mobi',
    #         ' odt rar', 'ZIP'}
    extl = {'.PDF', '.zip', '.7z', '.Pdf', '.wv', '.RAR', '.epub', '.pdF', '.gz', '.rar', '.mobi', '.ZIP'}
    fscopy = list()


    def walk(r):
        for r, dl, fl in os.walk(r):
            gfl = list()
            for file in fl:
                _, e = os.path.splitext(file)
                if e in extl:
                    gfl.append(file)
            if len(gfl) > 0:
                fscopy.append((r, gfl))
            else:
                pass

    walk('/srv/store')
    walk('/srv/private')

    # pickle.dump(pickle_file, fscopy)
    with open(pickle_file, 'w') as outfil:
        json.dump(fscopy, outfil, indent=4)


def ffind(f):
    for root, fl in fscopy:
        if f in fl:
            return os.path.join(root, f)
    return None
```

I was wondering if there's a better way to do it (or some pre-built lib).

Comment: **1** Your `ffind` just returns the path of the first file that matches `f`. Does that mean that all your files have unique base names, or do you always only want the first match? **2** I guess the contents of the disk array are stable, or you don't mind having to rebuild the whole cache if you add or remove any files.

Comment: Why are you using using `json.load()` to read in the `fscopy.pickle` file (and `json.dump()` to write it)?

Comment: **1** Your `walk` function is ok, but you could do it more compactly (and maybe more efficiently) using the new `pathlib` module. **2** You could make `ffind` _much_ faster if `fscopy` were a dictionary, using the filename as the key. **3** I just noticed that you're not actually using the `pickle` module, but you're calling your JSON file a pickle file. That's a little confusing. ;)

Comment: Aside from the issues already mentioned. Searching the cache could be improved a great deal—because what it is now is basically a linear search. It would be better to use a dictionary or set (or a combination of them) for faster lookups and other kind of membership testing.